# Why “p” for first item in list in Haskell’s quicksort example?

Tags: haskell

From [haskell.org](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction#Quicksort_in_Haskell):

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser  = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

My question is which word does “p” stand for here? In other words, why `(p:xs)` rather than `(x:xs)`?

Comment: Just as an aside.  Wouldn't this sort be faster if they wrote the third line like this `quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ ( p : quicksort greater)`

Comment: @DiegoNolan No, that's only one evaluation step forward from original version so I would expect ghc to optimize it away.

Comment: @DiegoNolan: Note that `++` is right-associative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just spotted the answer:

> `(p:xs)` pattern on its left-hand side standing for non-empty list with the head element `p` (used as a pivot element)

“p” stands for “pivot”.